# SQL - Find all inserts in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

long time listener, first time poster.  I'm new to SQL and am trying to help another co-worker build some scripts to use with a testing tool.  Our goal is to have something that can check a table against a set of criteria after an update to our application's code to make sure that the stored procedures are still generating expected data.

To that end (have I lost you yet?) I'm trying to find a way to find which tables and which columns in those tables are being updated by a given stored proc.  I've found a script that can tell me what tables a stored procedure uses, but I can't find a way to also find what columns are used.

This is what I have for finding the tables:

```
WITH stored_procedures AS (
SELECT
o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name, d.resultobj AS updated,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name) AS row
FROM sysdepends d 
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id
INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid
WHERE o.xtype = 'P' AND o.name = 'stored_procedure_here')
SELECT table_name FROM stored_procedures
WHERE row = 1 AND updated = 1 
ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
```

Any ideas?  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you know what the stored procedure is, read it and see to what tables it writes.  Then see if there are new records.  If the tables have recordCreatedDateTime fields, use those.  Otherwise, do a `select count(*)`, keep the result, run the application, and do another `select count(*)`.

Comment: You may find  the sp_depends built in stored proc of use to you as well.     sp_depends  'uspMyStoredProcName'

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for the response.  I see what you're saying, but I have a lot of stored procedures I'd need to manually read, so I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Hey Sql Surfer, can you explain that a little more?  I'm not sure what you mean or what that does exactly...

Comment: To get the columns you are going to have to put eyes on the code. You can utilize sysdepends to get an idea of what tables are involved but for column level you have to parse the sql and the most accurate method of doing that is with your eyes.

Comment: Do you care about side effects, e.g. triggers that might cause additional writes?

Comment: You can check the code of the procedures against the names of columns in the system tables/views, but you would get false positives if you have any columns named "SELECT" or anything that could be something other than a column name.

Comment: It looks like Sql Surfer's answer gives me what I want for now, or at least it seems to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create something like a "protocol-table" who keeps track of all inserts beeing made. This protocol table would be filled by a Trigger wich will be executed every time you insert a row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON tableName /*Name of table which will have a protocol*/
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO protocol-table (protocol_id, tableName_id,nameOfTable, GETDATE()) /*protocol_id could be an auto-generated key*/
SELECT NULL, tableName.idField,'tableName', NULL                        /*tableName_id is the ID-Field of the table you protocol*/
FROM inserted /*inserted is a "logical table". Leave this the way it is */

GO
```

Each time an `INSERT` is made to your table the `ID` of this `INSERT` and the name of the table who was affected by this `INSERT` would appear in the protocol.

The downside of this: You would have to do this for every table you have to make sure everything gets protocolled.